# How to add data on Top position like first in first out in For and while Loop? Reverse loop maybe?

Tags: php, html, for-loop, while-loop

I want these loops to add data on Top every time not in bottom.I did not find any solution how I can run these loop in reverse order

```
for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++){
    if($i==0) {
            $html.="<tr style='font-weight: bold;color:red;background-color:#EEEEEE;'>
            <td width='60'>".$data[$i][0]."</td>
            <td width='100'>".$data[$i][1]."</td>
            <td width='240'>".$data[$i][2]."</td>
            <td width='60'>".$data[$i][3]."</td></tr>";}
     else{
             $sc_=explode("-",$data[$i][3]);
            if(count($sc_)!=2){
            $html.="<tr><td>".$data[$i][0]."</td>
            <td>".$data[$i][1]."</td>
            <td>".$data[$i][2]."</td>
            <td>".$data[$i][3]."</td></tr>";
            }else{
            if($sc_[0]>$sc_[1]){
                $html.="<tr><td>".$data[$i][0]."</td>
                <td>".$data[$i][1]."</td>
                <td>".$data[$i][2]."</td>
                <td style='color:green;'>".$data[$i][3]."</td></tr>";
                }
            else if($sc_[0]<$sc_[1]){
                $html.="<tr><td>".$data[$i][0]."</td>
                <td>".$data[$i][1]."</td>
                <td>".$data[$i][2]." </td>
                <td style='color:red;'>".$data[$i][3]."</td></tr>";             
            }else{
                $html.="<tr><td>".$data[$i][0]."</td>
                <td>".$data[$i][1]."</td>
                <td>".$data[$i][2]."</td>
                <td>".$data[$i][3]."</td></tr>";                                
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And This is the second loop in my Code

```
while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE)
        { 
          $data[] = $row;
        }
```

I want to add data on top in every iteration like new values on line 1 every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `for` loop as:

```
for($i = count($data) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    if($i == count($data) - 1) {
         // show table head
```

In this case you will take items from **the end** of `$data` array as `$i` will be decreasing.

Comment: I did this but it is not showing anything now like no output blank page only

Comment: My fault - use `$i>=0` not `<=`.

Comment: Thank you so much bro It is working. Just having one issue my table header is going to bottom now :(

Comment: Show table head when `$i == count($data) - 1`, I already mentioned it in the answer.

Comment: I did but It is replacing header with new values and header is in the end of every data now

Comment: Here'a simplified working example. Sync your code with it https://3v4l.org/mmAMX

Comment: Sir actually I'm new in this field and I don't know much how to do all these thats why I'm asking please I just want to resolve this now how this header should not be replaced with new values

Comment: I advise to ask another question with the exact code which causes error. It will be easier to understand what is wrong seeing the code.

Comment: can you tell me how I can run while loop in reverse order in my above code?

Comment: This is my code data is comming from a simple HTML form I want to add data in text file. Data is saving in text file but I want to add new data on top position like first in first out. I followed your code above but that is only showing in table but in text file it is saving new data below already existing data. Here is my code                 https://3v4l.org/3cfjk

Comment: Your initial question was about outputting data in html table in __reverse order__. If question is solved - please do not write any other questions in comments. Ask __new question instead__, it's free.

Comment: I asked that and waited for two days nobody answered so I deleted that question and then asked this question.